# Is there any way to create an array of buttons in Visual Studio 2017 C++/CLI from scratch?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

I´m making a project in which I´m connecting two different devices via UDP and I need to create an array of buttons from scratch to represent bits, so if a recieve for example the number 0x8A (1000 1010b) my array of 8 buttons will display 1´s and 0´s depending on the number.

I´ve been reading but most of the tutorials about c++ and GUI uses drag and drop for the elements, but I need the array of buttons for an easy access to each button.

I´m using Visual Studio 2017, the C++/CLI project.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: C++/CLI is a language from Microsoft intended to allow C# or other .Net languages to interface with unmanaged C++. In that scenario, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. If you're still learning C++, please do *not* start with C++/CLI. In order to effectively write in C++/CLI, one should already know both C++ and C#, and then there's still things to learn about C++/CLI. If you want to learn C++ GUIs, stick with unmanaged C++ and MFC. (In Visual Studio, create a "Win32" C++ project.) If you want to learn managed GUIs, then I would use C# with either WinForms or WPF.

Comment: It is not very obvious what itch you are trying to scratch.  Consider a `List<Button^>^` variable.

Comment: Thank you both, I will use Win 32 project instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "from scratch" means "dynamically at runtime".

Based on your example of receiving the number 0x8A, it sounds like you only need 8 buttons. If that's the case, then I'd create the buttons at design time, not at runtime. Creation at runtime is most appropriate when you don't know ahead of time how many there will be, but if you know it will be exactly 8, then creation at design time is most appropriate.

If my inference is incorrect, and you do not know how many buttons until runtime, then we'd need to know which GUI toolkit you're using to give a concrete answer. Other than that, all we can do is give a general outline.

```
// Keep this around somewhere so you can access the buttons later.
List<ButtonOfSomeSort^>^ buttons = gcnew List<ButtonOfSomeSort^>();

for (int i = 0; i < numButtonsToCreate; i++)
{
    ButtonOfSomeSort button = gcnew ButtonOfSomeSort();
    // set some properties on the button, such as text, size & position, and click handler.
    someContainerControlInYourGUI.Add(button);
    buttons.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I need 54 buttons to represent 54 bits.
I´m using Visual studio, a C++/CLI project but I haven´t found a tutorial with the code to create a button from scratch they always use the drag and drop tool, I will try with your code, maybe I´ll need to change the type of project, but thank you very much.